# 'using' keyword in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

I got two structures ('AAA' and 'BBB') containing the same var name ('aa') and a third structure ('CCC') defined using both through multiple inheritance.
[ the two structures are supposed to be unrelated, so this is not the famous diamond issue when two classes have a common ancestor ].
for the derived struct 'CCC' I tried to choose explicitly to work with the var in the derived struct 'AAA' but gcc still complains about ambiguous def. why?

```
struct AAA { int aa; };
struct BBB { int aa; };
struct CCC : public AAA , public BBB { using AAA::aa; };
int main() { CCC ccc; return ccc.aa; }
```

gives:

```
x.cpp: In function 'int main()':
x.cpp:4:34: error: request for member 'aa' is ambiguous
x.cpp:2:18: error: candidates are: int BBB::aa
x.cpp:1:18: error:                 int AAA::aa
```

Comment: I'd personally _really_ just use a name that doesn't conflict. Alternatively, use the scope resolution operator, which admittedly looks a bit funny in this case, but very clearly expresses what it is you want:  `ccc.AAA::aa`.

Answer (score 5):

It fails because aa is already in that scope. `using AAA.aa` is only going to bring it into the scope again.

you can cast this to the type and extract it that way.

```
#include <iostream>
struct AAA { 
    int aa; 
    AAA() : aa(1) {}
    virtual ~AAA(){};
};
struct BBB { 
    int aa;
    BBB() : aa(5) {}
    virtual ~BBB(){};
};

struct CCC : public AAA , public BBB 
{ 
    CCC() : AAA(), BBB() {}
//  using AAA::aa; 
};

int main() 
{ 
    CCC ccc; 
    std::cout << static_cast<BBB*>(&ccc)->aa << std::endl;
}
```

Although if this is somehting you intend to do a lot of it might be easier just encapsulate that functionality.

```
//member of CCC
int get_aa()
{
    return static_cast<BBB*>(this)->aa;
}
```

Comment: using a function or a cast is (more or less) the sane as using

Comment: no it ins't this actually works, using brings the member into the current scope/namespace. both aa in BBB and AAA are already in CCC, the using command IS NOT going to pick a default for the compiler to work with.

Comment: just tried with a shared function (instead of a var) and the 'using' seems to do the job. also - works fine with variables on Visual c++

Answer (score 0):

You can set pointers to relevant members:

```
struct AAA { int aa; };
struct BBB { int aa; };
struct CCC : public AAA , public BBB { 
  int *A_aa; int *B_aa;
  CCC(): 
          A_aa(&static_cast<AAA*>(this)->aa), 
          B_aa(&static_cast<BBB*>(this)->aa) { } 
};

int main() { CCC ccc; return *ccc.A_aa; }
```

Comment: I personally would advise against this approach as it isn't very idiomatic. Also I advise using references rather than pointers where possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance). For you example this code should be rewrited in this way:

```
struct AAA { int aa; };
struct BBB { int aa; };
struct CCC : virtual public AAA , virtual public BBB { using AAA::aa; };
```